# error calling the object from jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

```
var accordion = {

init: function(options, elem) {
var self = this;

self.elem = elem;

self.options = $.extend( {}, $.fn.accordion.options, options );

// call methods
self.hideDD();
},

hideDD: function() {
    var self = this;

    $(self.elem + ' dd').hide();
}
```

};

Inside hideDD method, `$(self.elem + ' dd').hide();` gives error if `self.elem` is there, it works only if I just put `$('dd').hide()` but I dont want that as it selects all DD elements on the page.

Why isn't it working as it is?

Comment: is `self.elem` a string?

Comment: Have you checked what `self` actually points to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.find()` method as your selector is invalid:

```
$(self.elem).find('dd').hide();
```

When you use `$(self.elem + ' dd')` you basically want: `$($(self.elem).selector + ' dd')` but this is just wrong as you wrap twice element in jquery object and BTW, selector property of jquery object is deprecated. So simplest solution here is to search for descendants of self.element, you can then use `.find()` method or other method as `.children()` for direct descendants.

Comment: Thats't it! Though there is an error in your syntax. Should be $(self.elem).find('dd').hide(); Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`self.elem + ' dd'` is constructing a string. I don't think `self.elem` contains a string; it contains an object. The result of that string concatenation, then, is something as deliciously stupid as `"[object Object] dd"`.

So, instead, try this to search only children of your DOM object:

```
$(self.elem).find('dd').hide();
```